# gcc in-memory-compiling

Tags: gcc

There is a need for a program (written in c) to do the following.

1. take a few lines of user input
2. generate a  C program basing on the input
3. compile the generated c program and create a .so file and dynamically link to to main and execute it.

A key requirement is: the generated C program should not be on File system, because the generated C program has the trade secret. Yes, this mechanism is far from foolproof, but it is better than nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GCC isn't really made for embedding like that. Instead I recommend you look at [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and [LLVM](http://llvm.org/).

Comment: Thanks Joachim for the links, they look interesting. Still hope there is a (potentially ugly) workaround since most of the infrastructure was done using GCC.

Comment: Don't. Either your trade secret is **secret** (as in cryptography), or you shouldn't bother hiding it. Obfuscation makes all the wrong people *feel* secure, while in reality they are anything but.

Comment: Agree that this will not deter the most determined user from finding the secret, but it will help prevent  casual attempts to look into it. So in the absence of better protection, I will need it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use memory filesystem as a destination for your .so, like this `sudo mount -osize=10M tmpfs /home/chill/tmp/supersikrit -t tmpfs`

Comment: Thanks Chill for the idea. However, in the case when user runs your executable and kill it in the middle (ctrl-C etc), the residual files (some generated source code) will be left in the memory file system.